# Query a Model regarding its ICollection<> asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Using EntityFramework6 Code-First mvc 5 I have the following model:

**Course**

```
public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        EnrolledStudentsEmails = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> EnrolledStudentsEmails { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to query the following to IPagedList(Courses)

```
var model =
            (from c in db.Courses
             where searchTerm == null ||
             c.Id.StartsWith(searchTerm) ||
             c.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm)

             select new
             {
                 Id = c.Id,
                 Name = c.Name,
                 Description = c.Description,
                 UserName = c.UserName


             }).AsEnumerable().Select(c => new Course
             {
                 Id = c.Id,
                 Name = c.Name,
                 Description = c.Description,
                 UserName = c.UserName
             }).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

What should be the type of the ICollection EnrolledStudents if I want to use the AspNetUsers table generated when using user authentication?

The upper LINQ gets me All the courses in the database.

how can I get the courses that **example@123.com** is enrolled in?
Is it possible using my model? should I change my model?

**Knowing that I can access the Email using:**

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Yes, The one generated when creating asp.net app using user authentication template

Answer (score 0):

If your existing code works, your models are correct and you just want to filter by a known email, just use your collection:

```
var emailFilter = "example@123.com";
var model =
            (from c in db.Courses
             where (searchTerm == null ||
               c.Id.StartsWith(searchTerm) ||
               c.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm)) &&
               c.EnrolledStudentsEmails.Any(e => e.Email == emailFilter)

             select new
             {
                 Id = c.Id,
                 Name = c.Name,
                 Description = c.Description,
                 UserName = c.UserName


             }).AsEnumerable().Select(c => new Course
             {
                 Id = c.Id,
                 Name = c.Name,
                 Description = c.Description,
                 UserName = c.UserName
             }).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```